# M2_HOME not working in IntelliJ on OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

ive tried :

```
echo $M2_HOME
/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.3
```

seemd like M2_HOME is set

and the file **/etc/launchd.conf** looks like this:

```
setenv $M2_HOME /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.3
```

ive restarted the mac and still nothing works ...

any idea ?

Comment: you need to remove the $ from the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout :

*"and the file **/etc/launchd.conf** looks like this:"*

change :

```
setenv $M2_HOME /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.3
```

to

```
setenv M2_HOME /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new file /Library/LaunchDaemons/setenv.M2_HOME.plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
      <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>setenv.BAR</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
      <array>
        <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
        <string>setenv</string>
        <string>M2_HOME</string>
        <string>/opt/local/share/java/apache-maven-3.1.1</string>
      </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
      <key>ServiceIPC</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Then restart the computer, or execute

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/setenv.M2_HOME.plist
```

Relaunch IDEA, and it picks up MAVEN_HOME. Tested on Yosemite 10.10.3.

Source: http://lajosd.blogspot.be/2015/06/place-following-content-enhance-it-to.html